# Why do devices not connect to shared WiFi after updating to Monterey?

Tags: monterey, internet-sharing

After updating to Monterey yesterday, WiFi sharing is no longer functional. I can create the network, and other devices can see it, but connection always fails.

I've tried resetting the SMC and it made no difference.
Does anyone have any ideas what is going wrong or how I can fix this?

I'm sharing from ethernet.

Comment: Could you give more info ? Mac intel or M1. Device sharing connection ?…

Comment: 2019 Intel Macbook Pro 15 inch. Tried connecting with an iPhone and a Meta Quest 2.